# Peek definition in HTML Tools for Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I was checking the extension HTML Tools for Visual Studio and I found very useful the Peek definition functionality allowing you to edit css files while you're in html. My problem is that I work in ASP .NET Web Pages, using .apsx files to develop, which haven't got this feature.

Do you know if there is any way to enable this peek definition for .aspx files?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to The CSS Peek extension, you can enable .aspx files from the configuration settings. Just go to your VSCode settings and edit the `cssPeek.peekFromLanguages` settings to add "aspx"